# Spring @Repository annotation does not work but @Service annotation does?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a simple Class called BeaconDao

```
    package za.co.idealize.dao.impl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import za.co.idealize.dao.BaseDao;
    import za.co.idealizeit.model.Beacon;

    @Service("beaconDao")
    public class BeaconDao extends BaseDao{

        @Autowired
        protected BeaconDao(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            super(sessionFactory, Beacon.class);

        }

        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List findByStoreID(int storeID) {
            Session session = getSession();

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery(
                    "FROM Beacon b where b.storeId = :id");
            q.setParameter("id",storeID);

            List beacon = q.list();

            tx.commit();
            return beacon;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List findByUUID(String UUID) {
            Session session = getSession();

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            List beacon = session.createQuery(
                    "FROM Beacon where Beacon.Uuid = " + UUID).list();
            tx.commit();
            return beacon;
        }

    }
```

Whenever i start my application up with the beaconDAO marked @Repository the application comes back with the following stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beaconJsonController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beaconJsonController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:287)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:266)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
        ... 43 more
    Jun 24, 2014 1:30:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beaconJsonController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beaconJsonController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:287)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:266)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
        ... 43 more
```

however when i mark the beaconDao with @Service or @Component everything works perfectly fine.
Can anyone see an issue here?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository`? Can you post your config and the code (including imports) with the @Repository annotation?

Comment: @KevinBowersox My instinct was the same. OP, note that the root error here is `Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30`

Comment: Are you using AOP in your application?

Comment: thank you very much for your replies. I a not using AOP however I found the below answer helpful. I am still unclear as to why 'code'@Respository'code' does not work without using an interface but 'code'@service'code' and 'code'@component'code' annotations allow you to use the concrete class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies entirely elsewhere:

`Can not set za.co.idealize.dao.impl.BeaconDao field za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController.beaconDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30`.

Now, if I were to translate that to English then the translation would be: Spring cannot set beaconDao field on `za.co.idealize.controller.BeaconJsonController` singleton because JDK proxies are used and you have declared the `BeaconJsonController.beaconDao` as BeaconDao class when you should have used some kind of interface. I suspect your BeaconDao class hierarchy looks someting like `BeaconDao` -> `BaseDao`  -> `ISomeDao` where ISomeDao is an interface. Change the declaration in `BeaconJsonController` from

```
private BeaconDao beaconDao;
```

to

```
private ISomeDao beaconDao;
```

and use qualifier if you must. 
The problem is that Spring will create proxy for `ISomeDao` interface rather than for `BeaconDao` and you then tries to assign ISomeDao proxy to BeaconDao field which causes the class cast exception.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer it worked when i used an interface. i am still unclear as to why '@Service' and '@Component' work with a concrete class but '@Repository' works with the interface. I was under the impression that '@service' and '@conponent' are merely sub annotations to the '@Component' annotation

Comment: @dimoniy, Hi, your answer solved a huge problem for my project. Thank you for that. But if you could explain what "you have declared the BeaconJsonController.beaconDao as BeaconDao class when you should have used some kind of interface" this means, that'd be great. Why do I need to use an interface instead of the class itself?

Comment: @SajibAcharya Spring uses two kinds of proxies: JDK proxies and CGLIB proxies. The JDK proxies only works with interfaces, so when you create any kind of object through spring and JDK proxies are used, Spring can only recognize and wire interfaces.